# Definir formato de data e hora usado por DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datetime

Tenho uma aplicação onde tem se hora de registro, que uso `DateTime.Now`, e uma data inicial e data final que o usuário informa. Ao mostrar esses dados em uma `DataGrid` eles estão no formato `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt`. Quero que seja mostrado no padrão brasileiro dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm. Como posso definir isto para o `DateTime`?

DataGrid:

[image: SS]

Comment: O que você já tentou? Como está seu código? Tentou `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DataInicio, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm\}}" />`?

Comment: Perfeito, era isso mesmo que eu não estava conseguindo fazer. Não sabia como definir o formato a ser mostrado. Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisa formatar a coluna desta forma:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DataInicio, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm\}}" />
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WPF/DateTimeFormat.xaml).

Answer (score 2):

Tente:

```
 DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}"
```